# Why cant I change color of my JFRame background when I use setLayout()?

Tags: java

I try to set background color to red for JFrame while keeping white color to JPanel.
But it doesnt work with setLayout somehow

```
    private void buildGraphics(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    setTitle("Application");
    setBounds(100, 100, 600, 400);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    frame.setBackground(Color.red);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBounds(50, 50, 500, 70);
    panel.setBackground(Color.white);
    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Click to choose..."));
    panel.add(button1);
    panel.add(button2);
    panel.add(button3);
    getContentPane().add(panel);


}
```

Comment: To me it looks like the instance of the frame you created will never be used.
The panel is drawn on another element.

Comment: Why are you setting the layout to null? You never do anything to set the size of your content pane. Can you explain the behavior you get versus the behavior you expect?

Answer (score 0):

You already have a frame (your class is extending `JFrame`, so it IS a `JFrame`) and `buildGraphics()` has to build the existing frame you don't have to create a new one:

```java
private void buildGraphics() {

    this.setTitle("Application");
    this.setBounds(100, 100, 600, 400);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    this.setBackground(Color.red);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    panel.setBounds(50, 50, 500, 70);
    panel.setBackground(Color.white);
    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Click to choose..."));
    panel.add(button1);
    panel.add(button2);
    panel.add(button3);

    this.getContentPane().add(panel);

}
```

Comment: When I do this first alternative, my Panel dosent show up :/

Comment: and color dosent change to red

Comment: Try the second alternative then, I think it's your intent: `getContentPane().add(panel)` is not adding the panel to new JFrame you've created with `JFrame frame = new JFrame();` but to `this`, so simply remove references to `frame`

Comment: Maybe its better to have another panel on the background and set its color?

Comment: Are you extending `JFrame` in the class where `buildGraphics` is written?

Comment: Yest I extend Jframe in this class

Comment: Ok, use the second solution then. Basically all you are doing in `buildGraphics()` must effect your class, that means your class is already a JFrame and you can use its methods without creating a new one. I'll edit my solution

Comment: Thanks for taking your time

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I now created another JPanel and put my first one inside to control background color

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    setTitle(" Application");
    setBounds(100, 100, 600, 400);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JPanel panelMain = new JPanel();
    panelMain.setBounds(5, 5, 595, 395);
    panelMain.setBackground(Color.red);
    getContentPane().add(panelMain);


    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBounds(50, 50, 500, 70);
    panel.setBackground(Color.white);
    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("What would you like to do?"));
    panel.add(button1);
    panel.add(button2);
    panel.add(button3);
    panelMain.add(panel);
```

Comment: What do you want to happen here?